# ¿Se puede saber cuándo el usuario da click en un botón desde otra página?

Tags: javascript, html5

Por ejemplo, tengo un botón para generar informes, entonces mi duda es si desde otra página puedo saber cuándo un usuario da click sobre ese botón

Comment: Si es posible, uno de los muchos ejemplos,uno de ellos podría ser que ese botón se vincule con una base de datos, y que al momento de presionar el botón, envié información a la base de datos, la cual, te proporcionara, fecha hora y si es necesario quien presiono dicho  botón. Luego obtienes esa información y la interpretas en tu otra pagina.

Comment: Es totalmente posible y se puede realizar de muchas maneras. tanto usando `LocalStorage - Base De datos etc..` Si deseas que te ayudemos con ese codigo tendras que darnos al menos un indicio de lo que quisieras o llevas hasta ahora, Saludos.

Comment: Lo que necesito es que al momento que el usuario genere un reporte, en la vista del administrador aparezca una notificación que tal usuario genero el reporte

Comment: A la hora de aplicar dicho reporte guarda en la base de datos tambien el nombre del usuario que realizo dicho reporte y lo imprimes en la notificacion en la parte de administracion

Comment: Vale, a ver cómo sale, gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Si bien existen otras formas mejores para resolver lo que planteas específicamente, por ejemplo usando la base de datos, existe una solución bastante sencilla y poco conocida que involucra modificar el comportamiento del navegador al seguir un vínculo.

La idea sería agregar un atributo `ping` al tag `<a>`, de esta manera:

```
<a href="https://www.una_web.com/" ping="trackeamos.php">Un link</a>
```

La idea de `ping` es que cuando un usuario hace click en el vínculo, el navegador hace un **POST** a la url que le pasamos a `ping`, en este caso: *trackeamos.php*. De esta manera, desde *trackeamos.php* sabemos en el momento exacto en el que se hizo click. Esta característica es usada por algunos anunciantes para auditar los clicks en los anuncios.

El POST que se envía es vacío, pero del lado del servidor se puede detectar el `REMOTE_ADDR`, `referrer` o como se llame en el lenguaje del servidor que se use, es decir la url que realizo el request. La tabla de compatibilidad de los navegadores [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility).

El navegador hace el POST en segundo plano por lo que no lo vamos a ver en la consola.